# Elastic Beanstalk environment not executing commands in .ebextensions folder

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment running PHP. In my project I have an .ebextensions folder and a file named '15-memorymonitor.config' which contains the following;

```
container_commands:
  00download:
    command: "wget http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudwatch-samples/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-v1.1.0.zip"
    ignoreErrors: true
  01extract:
    ignoreErrors: true
  02rmzip:
    command: "rm CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-v1.1.0.zip"
    ignoreErrors: true
  03cdinto:
    command: "mv aws-scripts-mon/ /home/ec2-user"
    ignoreErrors: true
  04cron:
    command: "crontab -l | { cat; echo '* * * * * /home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail'; } | crontab -"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

The problem is that none of these commands seem to be executing when the application is deployed. I've checked the cfn.init file for references to the commands in the config file, and there are none.

Here's the contents of the cfn.init file.

```
2017-01-03 15:02:21,666 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:02:21,689 [INFO] Running configSets: _OnInstanceBoot
2017-01-03 15:02:21,690 [INFO] Running configSet _OnInstanceBoot
2017-01-03 15:02:21,692 [INFO] Running config AWSEBBaseConfig
2017-01-03 15:02:21,697 [INFO] Command clearbackupfiles succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,744 [INFO] Running config AWSEBMessageOfTheDay
2017-01-03 15:02:21,749 [INFO] Command 01clearoriginal succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,753 [INFO] Command 02createbanner succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,809 [INFO] Command 03updatebanner succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,815 [INFO] Running config AWSEBULimitConfig
2017-01-03 15:02:21,818 [INFO] Command 00removebackup succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,823 [INFO] Running config Infra-InstallContainerHooksPkg
2017-01-03 15:02:21,827 [INFO] Command 00mkdir succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,939 [INFO] Command 01download_container_hooks succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,976 [INFO] Command 02install_container_hooks succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,980 [INFO] Command 03cleanup succeeded
2017-01-03 15:02:21,986 [INFO] Running config Infra-WriteLeaderTestScript
2017-01-03 15:02:21,991 [INFO] Running config Infra-WriteTailLogsConf
2017-01-03 15:02:21,996 [INFO] Running config Infra-WriteSystemTailLogsConf
2017-01-03 15:02:22,002 [INFO] Running config Infra-WriteBundleLogsConf
2017-01-03 15:02:22,006 [INFO] Running config Infra-WritePublishLogsConf
2017-01-03 15:02:22,009 [INFO] Running config Infra-WritePublishLogsCron
2017-01-03 15:02:22,011 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-01-03 15:02:22,099 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:02:50,301 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:02:50,397 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-01-03 15:02:50,398 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-01-03 15:02:50,398 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-01-03 15:02:50,401 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:02:52,690 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:02:53,496 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-01-03 15:02:53,497 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-01-03 15:02:53,497 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-01-03 15:02:53,500 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:09:21,577 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:09:21,599 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-01-03 15:09:21,600 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-01-03 15:09:21,600 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-01-03 15:09:21,603 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:09:24,358 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2017-01-03 15:09:24,472 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-01-03 15:09:24,473 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-01-03 15:09:24,473 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2017-01-03 15:09:24,475 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
```

Does anyone have any idea why these commands wouldn't be executing?

I deploy my application via the AWS web console (as a zip file).

Comment: I am having the same problem at the moment. I have checked all the logs, rebuilt the environment, passed the file through a lint checker and still doesn't seem to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this. I was deploying my application via the AWS console and for some reason it wasn't extracting the config files.

To make it work, I deployed the application via the eb cli tool instead, and it worked!

You can read more about the eb cli in the link below;
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html